# How can I convert a WPF control into an image?

Tags: wpf, image

Is there an easy way to convert a WPF visual into an image?
If so, what's the code?

Comment: The title on this question doesn't seem to match the question. A control and a visual of the control are not the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not terribly difficult although you will probably want to wrap up functionality.  I would take a look at [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) the MSDN page has example usage.

The article [How to: Create a Bitmap from a Visual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969775.aspx) is linked near the bottom of the page.