# How to save drawn ellipse over canvas as an image - Windows RT

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I've drawn ellipse over canvas, now how can I save it as an image. I know you cannot directly save canvas as an image and neither you can take screenshot. I am working in C#/xaml. Below is my code for drawing ellipse over canvas.

```
private void canvasDraw_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (drawing)
        {
            PointerPoint current = e.GetCurrentPoint((UIElement)sender);
           // Line line = new Line() { X1 = start.Position.X, Y1 = start.Position.Y, X2 = current.Position.X, Y2 = current.Position.Y };
            //line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            Ellipse circle = new Ellipse();
            circle.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, current.Position.X);
            circle.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, current.Position.Y);
            circle.Height = 20;
            circle.Width = 20;
            circle.Fill = currentBrush;
            circle.Opacity = 0.7;
            circle.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty,1);
            canvasDraw.Children.Add(circle);

        }
    }
```

Edit : I am able to save the image by using InkManager. I stored every Ellipse in inkmanager and called SaveAsync method but the final issue is the image comes in black for example if I draw red ellipse the saved image has black ellipse.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468590/how-can-i-convert-a-wpf-control-into-an-image  ???

Comment: I think you need to clarify your tags here. Instead of `wpf` and `xaml`, maybe you mean `winrt-xaml`? Instead of `windows-rt`, maybe you mean `windows-runtime`?

Comment: That is not a duplicate question of the above one as it's for win-rt not wpf

Comment: You can check this answer to a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627830/creating-bitmap-image-from-xaml-control-using-writablebitmapex/13020721#13020721

Comment: You are the man, love you. I am able to do this with the help of your toolkit.

Comment: WriteableBitmapExtensions.DrawEllipse(bitmap, (int)current.Position.X, (int)current.Position.Y, 0, 0, currentBrush.Color);

Comment: If I place it under my canvasDraw_PointerMoved event what do you think is their going to be any performance issue?

Comment: Ok I am facing some lag, I tried to save the x,y and color in generic list and after that for loop to create bitmap but the for loop takes forever to run. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Read this example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/2007/12/02/rendering-ink-and-image-to-a-bitmap-using-wpf.aspx

Code Extract from site:

```
// render InkCanvas' visual tree to the RenderTargetBitmap
RenderTargetBitmap targetBitmap =
    new RenderTargetBitmap((int)inkCanvas1.ActualWidth,
                           (int)inkCanvas1.ActualHeight,
                           96d, 96d,
                           PixelFormats.Default);
targetBitmap.Render(inkCanvas1);

// add the RenderTargetBitmap to a Bitmapencoder
BmpBitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(targetBitmap));

// save file to disk
FileStream fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
encoder.Save(fs);
```

Comment: RenderTargetBitmap is not available in windows-rt

Answer (score 0):

Yes **RenderTargetBitmap** it is not available in windows store app target to 8.0

Windows 8.1 APIs include the new **RenderTargetBitmap** class that allows to render to a bitmap with its RenderAsync methods.
you can now use this method 
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) although its not working with MediaElement which i need :(