# Convert a Grid element to Image in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a code snippet which is currently returned as Grid.

```
private Grid GetImage(PlacemarkList locationDetail)
{
    Grid gridPushPin = new Grid();
    ImageBrush img = new ImageBrush();
    img.ImageSource = locationDetail.preferredCashback.Equals("1") ? new BitmapImage {         
                           UriSource = Constants.CashbackIconUri,
                           DecodePixelWidth = 36, 
                           DecodePixelHeight = 59 
                       } : new BitmapImage {
                           UriSource = Constants.ATMIconUri, 
                           DecodePixelWidth = 36, DecodePixelHeight = 59
                       };
    TextBlock IndexText = new TextBlock();
    IndexText.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
    IndexText.Text = locationDetail.IndexNum.ToString();
    gridPushPin.Background = img;
    gridPushPin.Tag = locationDetail.bankAddress;
    gridPushPin.Tap += grid_Tap;
    return gridPushPin;
}
```

But I want to return the Grid as a Image(Convert the Grid I am generating to Image). Can anybody please help how to accomplish that.

Comment: maybe that? gridPushPin as Image;

Comment: It doesn't allow controls.grid to convert to controls.image

Comment: You want a screenshot of the contents of your `Grid`?

Comment: not screenshot, I want to use it against content of another control which takes only ImageBrush.

Comment: What kind of control *only* takes an `ImageBrush`? Surely it can take any `Brush`. Then you could use a [`VisualBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Sorry @Sheridan it takes Brush. So I want to convert my Grid to brush

Comment: What about `ImageBrush returnedImage = gridPushPin.Background as ImageBrush;`?

Comment: @iop That doesn't help, I am adding some texts in the Grid which won't be available in that way,.

Comment: @Subhamoy Probably you should wrap your grid within something like a helper class and use this as data transport.

Comment: @iop is there any example available for the same?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`VisualBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush(v=vs.110).aspx) to paint a copy of any `UIElement` onto any other. How about something like this:

```
<Rectangle Width="150" Height="150">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=NameOfYourGrid}" />
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: Is there anyway I could achieve it through code behind?

Comment: thanks..I just checked...I am using using Windows Phone 8.. :( where VisualBrush doesn't work...

Comment: Then you should add that important tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hey did you check this subject. I think what you need is here.

[How do I save all content of a WPF ScrollViewer as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934276/how-do-i-save-all-content-of-a-wpf-scrollviewer-as-an-image/24934693#24934693)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyWrapperClass
{
    private DataGrid dataGrid;

    public MyWrapperClass(DataGrid grid)
    {
        this.dataGrid = grid;

    }

    public DataGrid MyGrid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.grid;
        }

        set
        {
            this.grid = value;
        }
    }

    public ImageBrush MyImageBrush
    {
        get 
        { 
            this.grid.Background as ImageBrush;
        }

        set 
        { 
            this.grid.Background = value; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are creating a Grid, so you will return a Grid.

Create an image instead. Something like:

```
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = "myImageURL";
```

This is from memory so actual code may vary depending on what you need to do exactly.

Basically the `Source` of the image needs to be set similarly to how you're setting `ImageSource` in your current code, but you may opt to use pack URLs to use an image stored as a resource instead.

**Edit after clarifications in comments**: So you want to get the grid control as an image. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1468630/983064) should help.

Comment: Actually there are couple of things I am doing in my grid(adding a index text) thats why I need a grid. I have modified my question

Comment: OK, so you basically want a sort of screenshot of the grid?

Comment: Yes, sort of but I am not very sure screenshot will be exactly as the grid or not.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't explain what exactly it is that you need to do.

Comment: I want to get the screenshot only..Can you help me how could I get it?